# display one ul list in blocks

Tags: list, html-lists

It is possible to display on screen 'ul' list like this?:

```
<ul>
<li> a </li>   <li> f </li>  <li> k </li>
<li> b </li>   <li> g </li>  <li> k </li>
<li> c </li>   <li> h </li>  <li> l </li>
<li> d </li>   <li> i </li>  <li> m </li>
<li> e </li>   <li> j </li>  <li> n </li></ul>
```

I need to be everything in one ul  and li in blocks (for example 5 elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `column-count` CSS3

Try

```
ul {

    -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3; /*3 in those rules is just placeholder -- can be anything*/
}
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8C92Y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {width: 120px;}
li {margin: 0; padding:0; float: left; width: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try looking into `display: table-cell`. I'm almost certain its what you want.

[CSS-Tricks Display Property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Answer (score 0):

You use [CSS3 multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts). Apply following style to the UL:

```
UL {
    column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
}
```

(you may need to rearrange your LI as needed)

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2N7rB/**